# Android Picasso Library

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I used Picasso for loading custom image from api. but not working picasso image loader. Picasso place on RecyclerView.Adapter. retrofit used for json client. pls Explain.

```
if ( !(partnerChallenge.get(position).getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("null"))) {
                String url = partnerChallenge.get(position).getImage();
                Log.e("mDailyChallenge", url);

                String uu = "http://dev.e.lk/v2/badges_image/level1_v2.png";

                Picasso.with(context).load(url)..into(holder.iv_home_badge);
            }
```

I used above url variable to picasso but image is not loading. then i used uu variable to picasso it workig well.

This is my Logcat result

```
E/mDailyChallenge: http://dev.goyo.lk/v2/badges_image/level1_v2.png
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting in `logcat` ?

Comment: This is my log cat result                                                    
E/mDailyChallenge: http://dev.goyo.lk/v2/badges_image/level1_v2.png

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using an Old Version of Picasso Library. You will face many problem esp. devices running on newer Version of Android. I suggest you update your library.

Gradle file add:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Java

```
Picasso.get().load(URL.here).into(imageView1);
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.get().load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

[Picasso more details here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)